# how do I delay a CSS3 transition before starting?

Tags: css, css-transitions, fadeout, css-animations

I'm trying to display an element, wait 1second and then fade out the element using `css3 transitions`.

Here is what I have:

```
.el {
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 225ms;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    -moz-animation-duration: 225ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    animation-duration: 225ms;
}
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
@-moz-keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes fadeout {
    from { opacity: 1; }
    to { opacity: 0; }
}
.el {
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 500ms;
  -webkit-animation-name: fadeout;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 1000ms;
  -moz-animation-duration: 500ms;
  -moz-animation-name: fadeout;
  -moz-animation-delay: 1000ms;
  animation-duration: 500ms;
  animation-name: fadeout;
  animation-delay: 1000ms;
}
```

I thought `animation-delay` would be the way to go, but doing it like this, the element **appears** after 1000ms instead of **fading out** after 1000ms.

Any idea how to delay the `fadeout`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not add the extra delay time to your animation duration:

```
-webkit-animation-duration: 1500ms;
```

Where ~66%(1000ms) of the time is a delay:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeout 
{
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    66% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

*Note that i used this time as an example. You can calculate the percentage of the delay yourself*

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fyf4/)

---

I hope this is what you meant.

Comment: @C-Link it's a demo yea.

Comment: but I'm not seeing anything in the demo?

Comment: @C-Link check my updated fiddle. I did only make the `-webkit-` animation as an example.

Answer (score 2):

Even though there is already a correct answer, let me enumerate what you options are.

You want an element to begin at opacity of 1, and stay like this for a second. Then, you want to fade it away to opacity of 0 during 0.5 s. And you want it to stay at opacity 0 forever.

The problem here is that the initial state and the final state are differents, so the base state of the element can not be both (of course!).

If we make the base state opacity 0, the problem is at the beginning. We can solve it as in nkmol solution. (starting the animation right away. We can also leave the animation only for the 0.5s where the opacity changes, and change the opacity usiong animation-fill-mode: backwards;

Also, you could set the base element to opacity 1. Then the problem is to make the final opacity 0; that can be done set animation-fill-mode: forwards;